# JPA Get Master data with spesific LAZY line

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am newbee about JPA And I have some problems.
I have an object ProductModel it contains set of product.

```
/* ProductModel */
 @JsonManagedReference
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "productModel", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 private Set<Product> products;



    /* Product */
   @JsonBackReference
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "product_model_id", nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_P_PRODUCT_MODEL_ID"))
   private ProductModel productModel;
```

I'm trying to get product model with just one spesific product but. I get all products related by product model.

```
 @Query("SELECT pm FROM ProductModel pm INNER JOIN Product p  on pm.identifier = p.productModelId where p.identifier = :pId")
    List<ProductModel> findProductModelByP(@Param("pId") Long pId);
```

my retun likes

```
 ProductModel{
   .
   .
   products [
    product1{},
    product2{},
    .
    .
    productN{}
  ]
}
```

But I want

```
 ProductModel{
   .
   .
   products [
    product2{}
  ]
}
```

Is there anyone help me?
Best Regards

Comment: You can't do this with JPQL in one query. Either use SQL (which DB are you using) or filter the products list before serializing it to JSON

Comment: I'm using oracle 19c db

Comment: So you could do this directly with SQL. I would recommend that you read this: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/generation.html#GUID-6C3441E8-4F02-4E95-969C-BBCA6BDBBD9A

Comment: it is working thanx

Comment: Cool. Please post your solution as the answer. Maybe someone else is interested in this as well. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I used entity graph to solve this struggle